# How to convert this cURL to wp_remote_get?

Tags: plugin-development, curl, http-api

I want to convert curl to wp_remote_get.

```
    $url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';

    $curl_post = 'client_id=' . $client_id . '&redirect_uri=' . $redirect_uri . '&client_secret=' . $client_secret . '&code=' . $code . '&grant_type=authorization_code';
    $ch        = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post );

    $data = json_decode( curl_exec( $ch ), true );

    $http_code = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
```

Comment: You mean [`wp_remote_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/), not `*_get()`, right?

Comment: Using cURL functions is highly discouraged. Use wp_remote_get() instead.

I'm getting this error while using cURL

Comment: @Yogesh what exactly is giving you that message? CI tooling? `wp_remote_get` is for GET requests, `wp_remote_post` is for POST requests, you can't use `wp_remote_get` to POST a request

Comment: OK thanks, So what will be the converted code for [wp_remote_post()]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curl is sending a POST request, to convert this you'll want to use [`wp_remote_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/). As described in the documentation, the request arguments are the same as [`WP_Http::request()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Http/request/), so let's look there how we can replicate your current version.

- `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );` just sets the URL. Already doing this with `wp_remote_post()`
- `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );` tells that we want the result. `wp_remote_post()` is returning that by default.
- `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );` makes sure to send a POST request. `wp_remote_post()` does that by default.
- `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );` now this is an interesting one. Tells curl not to verify the https certificate. The corresponding argument that we need is `sslverify`.
- `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post );` specifies the fields to be posted. The corresponding argument that we need is `body`.

With this in mind, the result could look something like

```
$url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
$curl_post = 'client_id=' . $client_id . '&redirect_uri=' . $redirect_uri . '&client_secret=' . $client_secret . '&code=' . $code . '&grant_type=authorization_code';

$args = [
    'sslverify' => false,
    'body' => $curl_post,
];

$result = wp_remote_post($url, $args);
```

This should give you enough to play around with. It might be more readable to send the data as an array:

```
$curl_post = [
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    // ..
];
```

But that is up to you.

Check what exactly `$result` is. You might need to call `json_decode()` on its body.

Comment: Thank you @Kero